# Implementation of optee trust os on raspberry pi 3

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi, trustzone

I am trying to implement OP-TEE trust OS on Raspberry Pi 3, with a Raspbian OS. The OP-TEE website mentions that it supports both 32 bit and 64 bit architectures, but when I tried to implement, it is automatically runs aarch64 make files which aint compatible to my 32-bit Raspbian OS.
Anyway to force OP-TEE to run aarch32 make files?

Answer (score 0):

I only tried to build the OP-TEE OS for the Juno board but I believe in your `Makefile` there is a place to define the cross-compiler like my Makefile:

```
class Compiler():

    __aa32 = None
    __aa64 = None

    def AArch32():
        if not Compiler.__aa32:
            fn = "gcc-linaro-"+AARCH32_COMPILER_VSN+"-x86_64_arm-linux-gnueabihf.tar.xz"
            Compiler.__aa32 = Resource\
            (
                name="AArch32 compiler",
                baseurl="http://releases.linaro.org/components/toolchain/"\
                    +"binaries/"+COMPILER_RELEASE+"/arm-linux-gnueabihf/",
                filename=fn,
                dstdir="tools/gcc/",
                md5file=fn+".asc",
            )
        return Compiler.__aa32

    def AArch64():
        if not Compiler.__aa64:
            fn = "gcc-linaro-"+AARCH64_COMPILER_VSN+"-x86_64_aarch64-linux-gnu.tar.xz"
            Compiler.__aa64 = Resource\
            (
                name="AArch64 compiler",
                baseurl="http://releases.linaro.org/components/toolchain/"\
                    +"binaries/"+COMPILER_RELEASE+"/aarch64-linux-gnu/",
                filename=fn,
                dstdir="tools/gcc/",
                md5file=fn+".asc",
            )
        return Compiler.__aa64
```

Try to use the AARCH32 instead of AARCH64.